# Uncovering encryption codes

Tags: encryption, decryption, shellcode

What is the complexity level of finding an Encryption code when the source document and the encrypted one are available? In practical terms: Malware in the computer sends a document to the TPM and gets an encrypted version.

Comment: [Known-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack) if you just know the plaintext, or [chosen-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack) if you get to pick the plaintexts.

Comment: May be I will clarify some: I am interested in adaptive attacks, where I can select the source to be encrypted - "...In the adaptive chosen plaintext attack, the attacker is able to conduct interactive queries of the cipher. Subsequent plaintext queries are able to be made based on the results of previous attempts. Through this progressive attack, the cryptanalyst is able to make more advanced headway on breaking the cipher. A related technique is the Allied “gardening” technique used during WW2. In this technique..."

Comment: The short answer is that attacking a well-designed TPM shouldn't be possible for a non-state actor, assuming that the attacker doesn't have physical access to the TPM.  Assuming that you're the defender in this scenario, primary concerns include physical security and ensuring that the TPM is properly designed and utilized.  If the attacker does have physical access, then an advanced attacker who puts a decent bit of effort into it might break it.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity level will be down to the algorithm attempting to test against, the skill level of the attacker, the speed of the machine(s), and time.

Your scenario is a known plaint text attack. Where by the attacker adjusts their results based on what is inputting and then outputted.

You say attacking a TPM, while this is a reasonable example as the TPM in most modern computers makes use of strong algorithms such as AES I don't think even malware could conduct a meaninglful known plaint text attack against it in a feasible timeframe. Therefore in direct answer the complexity would be very difficult and impractical.